# How to test the same behaviour for multiple templated classes with different templates in Google Test?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am practicing sorting algorithms in C++ 17 and have implemented my unittests as follows (the following compiles and all tests are green):

```
template <typename T>
class SortingmethodTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:   
    T sortingmethod;

    static constexpr int amount_test_data[7] = {0, 4, 8, 10, 256, 1000, 1234};
};

using sortingmethods = ::testing::Types<STLSort<int>,
                                         InsertionSort<int>,
                                         ShellSort<int>,
                                         MergeSort<int>,
                                         OptimizedMergeSort<int>,
                                         QuickSort<int>>;

TYPED_TEST_SUITE(SortingmethodTest, sortingmethods);

TYPED_TEST(SortingmethodTest, sort)
{
    for (const auto& amount : this->amount_test_data)
    {
        Sortvector<int> test(amount);
        test.vul_random_zonder_dubbels(); // Fills the vector

        this->sortingmethod(test); // operator() of the sortmethod used (STLSort, InsertionSort, ...) sorts the vector

        ASSERT_TRUE(test.is_range());
        ASSERT_TRUE(test.is_gesorteerd());
        ASSERT_TRUE(std::is_sorted(test.begin(), test.end()));
    }
}

TYPED_TEST(SortingmethodTest, sort_reverse)
{
    // ...
}

TYPED_TEST(SortingmethodTest, sort_already_sorted)
{
    // ...
}

TYPED_TEST(SortingmethodTest, sort_empty)
{
    // ...
}
```

I would like to repeat the same tests for other types than ints, e.g.

```
STLSort<int>,
InsertionSort<int>,
ShellSort<int>,
MergeSort<int>,
OptimizedMergeSort<int>,
QuickSort<int>

STLSort<double>,
InsertionSort<double>,
ShellSort<double>,
MergeSort<double>,
OptimizedMergeSort<double>,
QuickSort<double>

STLSort<CustomType>,
InsertionSort<CustomType>,
ShellSort<CustomType>,
MergeSort<CustomType>,
OptimizedMergeSort<CustomType>,
QuickSort<CustomType>

...
```

How can I do this in C++ with google test as cleanly and with as much reuse as possible? I am getting lost in the jungle of typed tests and type-parameterized tests [1]: when should I use one or the other?

With kind regards,

Marten

[1] https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#type-parameterized-tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is often frustrating that the googletest API so far does not give us more of the
leverage of modern C++ to make test code concise, especially for the testing of
templates. But up through v1.8.x (the current release series at
this date) googletest has been committed to C++98 compatibility, and that is largely why.
Forthcoming releases 1.9.x will move on to C++11 compatibility, and we can hope
for a more powerful API.

Nevertheless it is possible to write reasonably concise and straightforward googletest code now to
do the sort of thing you want: that is, to unit-test congruent templates for varying values of just one
template parameter.

There's more than one way of doing it. Here is a worked example of one of them,
using [type-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#type-parameterized-tests).

We'll have a set of three templates

```
template<typename T> struct (AA|BB|CC) {...};
```

each of which provides (at least) the interface:

```
Name::Name(T const & u);
Name::operator int() const;
Name Name::operator+(Name const & u) const;
Name & Name::operator+=(Name const & u);
Name Name::operator-(Name const & u) const;
Name & Name::operator-=(Name const & u);
```

for `Name` = `(AA|BB|CC)`. We want to
unit-test this interface, for each of `(AA|BB|CC)`, each instantiated for
each of the six types:

```
char, int, float, AA<char>, BB<int>, CC<float>
```

So that's 18 instantiations to be tested:

```
AA<char>, AA<int>, AA<float>, AA<AA<char>>, AA<BB<int>>, AA<CC<float>>
BB<char>, BB<int>, BB<float>, BB<AA<char>>, BB<BB<int>>, BB<CC<float>>
CC<char>, CC<int>, CC<float>, CC<AA<char>>, CC<BB<int>>, CC<CC<float>>
```

To keep it short, we will implement just two generic tests. For objects
`a`, `b` and `c` of any instantiated test type:

- After `a = b + c; b += c`, then `a == b`.
- Given `b != c`, after `a = b - c; c -= b`, then `a != c`.

(At least, these properties should hold as long as the operations don't overflow or
lose precision, which I'll just avoid).

So we'll expect to see 36 tests all told.

For this illustration I don't care what `AA`, `BB` and `CC` are, apart from their common interface,
so I'm simply going to derive them identically from a single model, like so:

**some_types.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    template<typename T>
    struct bottom_type {
        using type = T;
    };

    template<template<typename ...> class C, typename ...Ts>
    struct bottom_type<C<Ts...>> {
        using type = typename C<Ts...>::type;
    };
}

template<typename T>
using bottom_t = typename detail::bottom_type<T>::type;

template<
    typename T,
    typename Enable = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<bottom_t<T>>>
>
struct model
{
    using type = bottom_t<T>;

    model() = default;
    model(model const &) = default;
    model(T const & t)
    : _t{t}{}

    operator type() const { return _t; }

    auto operator+(model const & u) const {
        return _t + u;
    }

    auto & operator+=(model const & u) {
        _t += u;
        return *this;
    }

    auto operator-(model const & u ) const {
        return _t - u;
    }

    auto & operator-=(model const & u ) {
        _t -= u;
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    type _t = 0;
};

template<typename T> struct AA : model<T>{ using model<T>::model; };
template<typename T> struct BB : model<T>{ using model<T>::model; };
template<typename T> struct CC : model<T>{ using model<T>::model; };
```

Now here's my googletest code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "some_types.h"

template<typename T>
struct fixture : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:

    template<typename U>
    static auto const & test_data() {
        using type = bottom_t<U>;
        static std::array<type,1000> data;
        static bool called;
        if (!called) {
            std::default_random_engine gen;
            auto low = std::numeric_limits<type>::min() / 2;
            auto high = std::numeric_limits<type>::max() / 2;
            auto dist = [&low,&high](){
                if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<type>) {
                    return std::uniform_real_distribution<type>(low,high);
                } else {
                    return std::uniform_int_distribution<type>(low,high);
                }
            }();
            std::generate(
                data.begin(),data.end(),[&dist,&gen](){ return dist(gen); });
            called = true;
        }
        return data;
    }
};


template<template<typename> class C, typename ...Ts>
using test_types = ::testing::Types<C<Ts>...>;

using AA_test_types = test_types<AA,char,int,float,AA<char>,BB<int>,CC<float>>;
using BB_test_types = test_types<BB,char,int,float,AA<char>,BB<int>,CC<float>>;
using CC_test_types = test_types<CC,char,int,float,AA<char>,BB<int>,CC<float>>;

TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(fixture);

TYPED_TEST_P(fixture, addition)
{
    using wrapped_type = typename TypeParam::type;
    auto const & data = this->template test_data<wrapped_type>();
    auto fi = data.begin(); auto ri = data.rbegin();
    for ( ; fi != ri.base(); ++fi, ++ri)
    {
        TypeParam lhs{*fi}, rhs{*ri};
        auto sum = lhs + rhs;
        lhs += rhs;
        ASSERT_EQ(lhs,sum);
    }
}

TYPED_TEST_P(fixture, subtraction)
{
    using wrapped_type = typename TypeParam::type;
    auto const & data = this->template test_data<wrapped_type>();
    auto fi = data.begin(); auto ri = data.rbegin();
    for ( ; fi != ri.base(); ++fi, ++ri) {
        TypeParam lhs{*fi}, rhs{*ri};
        if (lhs != rhs) {
            auto diff = lhs - rhs;
            rhs -= lhs;
            ASSERT_NE(rhs,diff);
        }
    }
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(fixture,addition,subtraction);
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(AA_tests, fixture, AA_test_types);
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(BB_tests, fixture, BB_test_types);
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(CC_tests, fixture, CC_test_types);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Let's take in the points of interest:-

```
template<template<typename> class C, typename ...Ts>
using test_types = ::testing::Types<C<Ts>...>;
```

Here, I'm making `test_types` a template-alias for a `::testing::Types<SomeType...>` list
where `SomeType` will be an instantiation of one of the templates under test. As it
happens, my templates `AA`, `BB`, `CC` (like yours) are all of the form:

```
template<typename T> class;
```

so I want `test_types` to be a:

```
::testing::Types<C<Ts>...>
```

Then I define 3 concrete type aliases:

```
using AA_test_types = test_types<AA,char,int,float,AA<char>,BB<int>,CC<float>>;
using BB_test_types = test_types<BB,char,int,float,AA<char>,BB<int>,CC<float>>;
using CC_test_types = test_types<CC,char,int,float,AA<char>,BB<int>,CC<float>>;
```

which are respectively equivalent to:

```
::testing::Types<AA<char>, AA<int>, AA<float>, AA<AA<char>>, AA<BB<int>>, AA<CC<float>>>;
::testing::Types<BB<char>, BB<int>, BB<float>, BB<AA<char>>, BB<BB<int>>, BB<CC<float>>>;
::testing::Types<CC<char>, CC<int>, CC<float>, CC<AA<char>>, CC<BB<int>>, CC<CC<float>>>;
```

Then I define a type-parameterized test-suite with the template-fixture `fixture`.

```
TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(fixture);
```

Then I define my two type-parameterized test-patterns.

```
TYPED_TEST_P(fixture, addition)
{
    using wrapped_type = typename TypeParam::type;
    auto const & data = this->template test_data<wrapped_type>();
    auto fi = data.begin(); auto ri = data.rbegin();
    for ( ; fi != ri.base(); ++fi, ++ri)
    {
        TypeParam lhs{*fi}, rhs{*ri};
        auto sum = lhs + rhs;
        lhs += rhs;
        ASSERT_EQ(lhs,sum);
    }
}

TYPED_TEST_P(fixture, subtraction)
{
    using wrapped_type = typename TypeParam::type;
    auto const & data = this->template test_data<wrapped_type>();
    auto fi = data.begin(); auto ri = data.rbegin();
    for ( ; fi != ri.base(); ++fi, ++ri) {
        TypeParam lhs{*fi}, rhs{*ri};
        if (lhs != rhs) {
            auto diff = lhs - rhs;
            rhs -= lhs;
            ASSERT_NE(rhs,diff);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I register both of those patterns for instantiation with each instantiation
of `fixture`:

```
REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(fixture,addition,subtraction);
```

Then I create 3 instantiations called `(AA|BB|CC)_tests` of `fixture` for the
the test type-lists `(AA|BB|CC)_test_types` respectively:

```
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(AA_tests, fixture, AA_test_types);
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(BB_tests, fixture, BB_test_types);
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(CC_tests, fixture, CC_test_types);
```

And that's it. Compile and link:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o gtester main.cpp -lgtest -pthread
```

Run:

```
./gtester
[==========] Running 36 tests from 18 test suites.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from AA_tests/fixture/0, where TypeParam = AA<char>
[ RUN      ] AA_tests/fixture/0.addition
[       OK ] AA_tests/fixture/0.addition (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] AA_tests/fixture/0.subtraction
[       OK ] AA_tests/fixture/0.subtraction (1 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from AA_tests/fixture/0 (1 ms total)

[----------] 2 tests from AA_tests/fixture/1, where TypeParam = AA<int>
[ RUN      ] AA_tests/fixture/1.addition
[       OK ] AA_tests/fixture/1.addition (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] AA_tests/fixture/1.subtraction
[       OK ] AA_tests/fixture/1.subtraction (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from AA_tests/fixture/1 (0 ms total)
...
...
...
[----------] 2 tests from CC_tests/fixture/4, where TypeParam = CC<BB<int> >
[ RUN      ] CC_tests/fixture/4.addition
[       OK ] CC_tests/fixture/4.addition (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CC_tests/fixture/4.subtraction
[       OK ] CC_tests/fixture/4.subtraction (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from CC_tests/fixture/4 (0 ms total)

[----------] 2 tests from CC_tests/fixture/5, where TypeParam = CC<CC<float> >
[ RUN      ] CC_tests/fixture/5.addition
[       OK ] CC_tests/fixture/5.addition (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] CC_tests/fixture/5.subtraction
[       OK ] CC_tests/fixture/5.subtraction (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from CC_tests/fixture/5 (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 36 tests from 18 test suites ran. (4 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 36 tests.
```