# how can I get generate implement type for gtest?

Tags: c++, templates, googletest, template-meta-programming

there is some enum class like

```
enum class first{
        a,
        b,
        ...
};

enum class second{
        c,
        d,
        ...
};
```

the class seems like

```
template<first N, second M> class A{
        public:
                A(){}
                A(int n) {
                        var = n;
                }
                int var;
};
```

I wanto use it in gtest which is

```
template<typename T> class TestA : public ::testing::Test {};


TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestA);

TYPED_TEST_P(TestA, SomeTest){
            TypeParam x(0);
            EXPECT_EQ(x.var,0);
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestA, SomeTest);

typedef ::testing::Types<A<first::a, second::c>, A<first::b, second::d>...> MyTypes;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(My, TestA, MyTypes);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
            ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
            return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

how can i generate combinations of all possible template parameters
so it easily add test case by increasing enum number
maybe there is 3 or more param

```
::testing::Types<A<first::a, second::c>, A<first::a, second::c>, A<first::b, second::c>, A<first::b, second::c>>
::testing::Types<A<first::a, second::c, third::e>, A<first::a, second::c, third::f>...>
```

I try to contain them in template struct looks like this
then I cam make impl
just like

```
::testing::Combine(Base<first::a, first::b, ...>,Base<second::c, second::d, ...>;)
```

to generate

```
::testing::Types<A<first::a, second::c>, A<first::c, second::d>.....>
```

maybe there is 3 or more param

```
::testing::Types<A<000>, A<001>, A<010>, A<011>>.....
```

Comment: `A<00>` is not a valid type. Do you mean `A<first::a, second::c>`?

Comment: @bitmask yes, I use index instead

Comment: I do not understand question. Please state it more clearly. Here is [live demo of thing you already have](https://godbolt.org/z/xb81Wb58G). Are you trying generate combinations of all possible template parameters?

Comment: @MarekR edited.  yes, i want to test all combinations of them. And maybe can test more by add enum members.

Comment: For testing purposes this is an overkill. You should just use single example for template to be tested. Only if you have some specializations of template there is a seance to test example of this specialization and those are usually listed manually. Testing all possible combination is waste of resources. Do you have specializations for each enum value?

Comment: [Here is example how to generate combinations of types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55008790/1387438). It should be possible to tweak it for value parametrized templates.

Comment: @MarekR i have tried this one and others like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892577/how-to-test-the-same-behaviour-for-multiple-templated-classes-with-different-tem). I need to use template's scability to test heterogeneous computing.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your enums all have 0 as start value and do not contain gaps in between any two values then you can generate via the following approach (for any number of arguments/enums); note that this goes via an intermediate step of `std::tuple`s as for these there's `std::tuple_cat` available (instead of having to write an own, direct concatenation for `testing::Types` template); then we can go on and use `std::index_sequence` as another intermediate type so that we can keep index separation independent from any custom types and only rely on standard types to generate *arbitrary* sequences:

```
template <size_t ... N>
class Generate;

template <>
class Generate<>
{
public:
    using type = std::tuple<std::index_sequence<>>;
};

template <size_t N, size_t ... NN>
class Generate<N, NN...>
{
    template <size_t S>
    class Concat
    {
        template <size_t ... SS>
        std::index_sequence<S, SS...> concat(std::index_sequence<SS...>);
    public:
        template <typename ... T>
        auto operator()(std::tuple<T...> const& t)
            -> decltype(std::tuple(concat(T())...));
    };
    template <size_t ... S>
    static auto generate(std::index_sequence<S...>)
    {
        using Base = typename Generate<NN...>::type;
        return std::tuple_cat(Concat<S>()(Base())...);
    }

public:
    using type = decltype(generate(std::make_index_sequence<N>()));
};
```

The nested class allows to specify the single constants without having to specify the variadic types which would have been pretty cumbersome (if possible at all...). Note that the functions do not need to be implemented as they are only used within an unevaluated context.

However now we'd yet need to translate to our final target type (assuming you add `FMax` and `SMax` as respective last values to your two enums `First` and `Second` for easier finding of the one past the end value):

```
class Translate
{
    template <size_t F, size_t S>
    static auto translate(std::index_sequence<F, S>)
        -> A<static_cast<First>(F), static_cast<Second>(S)>;
    template <typename ... T>
    static auto translate(std::tuple<T ...> t)
        -> Types<decltype(translate(std::declval<T>()))...>;
    static auto constexpr FM = static_cast<size_t>(First::FMax);
    static auto constexpr SM = static_cast<size_t>(Second::SMax);

public:
    using type = decltype(translate(std::declval<Generate<FM, SM>::type>()));
};
```

Demonstration (with custom `A` and `Types` types) on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eW3ePPEne).

Comment: it works! only one thing is size_t param needs to static_cast to enum class. I have no idea where to add it. Using enum instead solved. thank you very very much!!

Comment: @三顿饭 Hm – actually it looks cleaner to me to fully separate generation of sequences from the generation of the final type. Adjusted...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my template tool, note this doesn't require use of integer sequence:

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <auto... values>
struct value_list {
    template <auto newValue>
    using append = value_list<values..., newValue>;

    template <template <auto...> typename T>
    using apply_on = T<values...>;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct concat_types_list;

template <template <typename...> typename Tem, typename... As>
struct concat_types_list<Tem<As...>> {
    using type = Tem<As...>;
};

template <template <typename...> typename Tem, typename... As, typename... Bs, typename... Remaning>
struct concat_types_list<Tem<As...>, Tem<Bs...>, Remaning...> {
    using type = typename concat_types_list<Tem<As..., Bs...>, Remaning...>::type;
};

template <typename... Ts>
using concat_types_list_t = typename concat_types_list<Ts...>::type;

template <typename... Ts>
struct value_generator {
    using type = value_generator;

    template <auto value>
    using for_each_append = value_generator<typename Ts::template append<value>...>;

    template <auto... Values>
    using mutiply = concat_types_list_t<for_each_append<Values>...>;

    template <template <typename...> typename Out, template <auto...> typename In>
    using compose = Out<typename Ts::template apply_on<In>...>;
};
}

using value_generator_t = detail::value_generator<detail::value_list<>>;
```

Use is quite nice:

```cpp
using MyTypes = value_generator_t
    ::mutiply<first::a, first::b, first::x, first::y>
    ::mutiply<second::c, second::e, second::f>
    ::compose<::testing::Types, A>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8d9e4Trqb

Comment: amaizing! perfectly suit my using. I just want it work as your post! thank you very much!!

Comment: Let others user spot better answers by voting/approving.

Comment: *'[...] doesn't require use of integer sequence'' – indeed, however instead requires specifying all enum members separately, which my approach in contrast avoids, the actual purpose of the sequences – no critisism, actually gave an upvote ;) Mine could be transformed to use arbitrary index (or better integer, based on the underlying type as another template paremeter) sequences, dropping `std::make_index_sequence` – and then comes the most interesting part, applicable to both answers (mine after modification): Let's generate the enum itself and the template/sequence via X-macros!

Comment: @Aconcagua this template pattern scales nicely, so when I have a moment will try address this issue you have mentioned.